# Pulseaudio errors - relevant files: Debian

Tags: debian, pulseaudio, alsa

I have inherited software which communicates with a MIDI device, so ALSA and pulseaudio are both involved. On the system B I have built from the ground, there are errors such as

```
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
```

and in the syslog:

```
Aug 24 17:43:29 debianl016 pulseaudio[2206]: [pulseaudio] client-conf-x11.c: xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
Aug 24 17:43:29 debianl016 pulseaudio[2204]: [pulseaudio] client-conf-x11.c: xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
Aug 24 17:43:29 debianl016 rtkit-daemon[1216]: Successfully made thread 2215 of process 2215 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '2003' high priority at nice level -11.
Aug 24 17:43:29 debianl016 rtkit-daemon[1216]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Aug 24 17:43:29 debianl016 pulseaudio[2215]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup without any loaded modules, refusing to work.
Aug 24 17:43:29 debianl016 pulseaudio[2206]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
Aug 24 17:43:29 debianl016 rtkit-daemon[1216]: Successfully made thread 2217 of process 2217 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '2003' high priority at nice level -11.
Aug 24 17:43:29 debianl016 rtkit-daemon[1216]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Aug 24 17:43:29 debianl016 pulseaudio[2217]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup without any loaded modules, refusing to work.
Aug 24 17:43:29 debianl016 pulseaudio[2204]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
Aug 24 17:43:29 debianl016 kernel: [  338.958104] usb 1-2.4: USB disconnect, device number 9
Aug 24 17:43:29 debianl016 kernel: [  339.256760] usb 1-2.4: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
Aug 24 17:43:30 debianl016 kernel: [  339.447919] usb 1-2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=04d8, idProduct=0059
Aug 24 17:43:30 debianl016 kernel: [  339.447939] usb 1-2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Aug 24 17:43:30 debianl016 kernel: [  339.447953] usb 1-2.4: Product: Lighted Rockers 01-016
Aug 24 17:43:30 debianl016 kernel: [  339.447964] usb 1-2.4: Manufacturer: 
Aug 24 17:43:30 debianl016 kernel: [  339.447976] usb 1-2.4: SerialNumber: 01-016
Aug 24 17:43:30 debianl016 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 12: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.4"
Aug 24 17:43:30 debianl016 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 12 was not an MTP device
Aug 24 17:46:27 debianl016 systemd-timesyncd[276]: interval/delta/delay/jitter/drift 512s/+0.002s/0.025s/0.005s/+53ppm
Aug 24 17:47:13 debianl016 minissdpd[753]: 1 new devices added
Aug 24 17:47:13 debianl016 minissdpd[753]: 1 new devices added
Aug 24 17:47:13 debianl016 minissdpd[753]: 1 new devices added
Aug 24 17:47:13 debianl016 minissdpd[753]: 1 new devices added
Aug 24 17:51:59 debianl016 pulseaudio[2839]: [pulseaudio] client-conf-x11.c: xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
Aug 24 17:51:59 debianl016 rtkit-daemon[1216]: Successfully made thread 2871 of process 2871 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '2003' high priority at nice level -11.
Aug 24 17:51:59 debianl016 rtkit-daemon[1216]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Aug 24 17:51:59 debianl016 pulseaudio[2871]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup without any loaded modules, refusing to work.
Aug 24 17:51:59 debianl016 pulseaudio[2839]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
Aug 24 17:51:59 debianl016 pulseaudio[2870]: [pulseaudio] client-conf-x11.c: xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
Aug 24 17:51:59 debianl016 rtkit-daemon[1216]: Successfully made thread 2874 of process 2874 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '2003' high priority at nice level -11.
Aug 24 17:51:59 debianl016 rtkit-daemon[1216]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Aug 24 17:51:59 debianl016 pulseaudio[2874]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup without any loaded modules, refusing to work.
Aug 24 17:51:59 debianl016 pulseaudio[2870]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
```

I also have a correct system A where pulseaudio is correctly configured, using lightdm. System B is on Gnome. BOTH are Debian 8 Jessie.

How can I compare relevant files across systems A and B to avoid these pulseaudio related errors?
Already verified:
`/etc/pulse/` is identical for systems A and B

EDIT: After a thorough reinstall of pulseaudio, errors persist. Current syslog:

```
Aug 24 18:42:26 debianl016 pulseaudio[4461]: [pulseaudio] client-conf-x11.c: xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
Aug 24 18:42:26 debianl016 pulseaudio[4462]: [pulseaudio] client-conf-x11.c: xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
Aug 24 18:42:26 debianl016 rtkit-daemon[1216]: Successfully made thread 4471 of process 4471 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '2003' high priority at nice level -11.
Aug 24 18:42:26 debianl016 rtkit-daemon[1216]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Aug 24 18:42:26 debianl016 pulseaudio[4471]: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Failed to find a working profile.
Aug 24 18:42:26 debianl016 pulseaudio[4471]: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="1" name="usb-CLASSIC_ORGAN_WORKS_CLASSIC_Lighted_Rockers_01-016_01-016-00-C01016" card_name="alsa_card.usb-CLASSIC_ORGAN_WORKS_CLASSIC_Lighted_Rockers_01-016_01-016-00-C01016" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
Aug 24 18:42:26 debianl016 rtkit-daemon[1216]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Aug 24 18:42:26 debianl016 rtkit-daemon[1216]: Successfully made thread 4483 of process 4471 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '2003' RT at priority 5.
Aug 24 18:42:26 debianl016 rtkit-daemon[1216]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Aug 24 18:42:26 debianl016 rtkit-daemon[1216]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Aug 24 18:42:26 debianl016 rtkit-daemon[1216]: Successfully made thread 4484 of process 4471 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '2003' RT at priority 5.
Aug 24 18:42:26 debianl016 rtkit-daemon[1216]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Aug 24 18:42:26 debianl016 pulseaudio[4471]: [pulseaudio] server-lookup.c: Unable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: /usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: No protocol specified
Aug 24 18:42:26 debianl016 pulseaudio[4471]: [pulseaudio] server-lookup.c: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.
Aug 24 18:42:26 debianl016 pulseaudio[4471]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Unable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: /usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: No protocol specified
Aug 24 18:42:26 debianl016 pulseaudio[4471]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.
Aug 24 18:42:26 debianl016 rtkit-daemon[1216]: Successfully made thread 4488 of process 4488 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '2003' high priority at nice level -11.
Aug 24 18:42:26 debianl016 rtkit-daemon[1216]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Aug 24 18:42:26 debianl016 pulseaudio[4488]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
```

pulseaudio --dump-modules:

```
module-alsa-card                        ALSA Card
module-alsa-sink                        ALSA Sink
module-alsa-source                      ALSA Source
module-always-sink                      Always keeps at least one sink loaded even if it's a null one
module-augment-properties               Augment the property sets of streams with additional static information
module-card-restore                     Automatically restore profile of cards
module-cli                              Command line interface
module-cli-protocol-tcp                 Command line interface protocol (TCP sockets)
module-cli-protocol-unix                Command line interface protocol (UNIX sockets)
module-combine                          Compatibility module (module-combine rename)
module-combine-sink                     Combine multiple sinks to one
module-console-kit                      Create a client for each ConsoleKit session of this user
module-dbus-protocol                    D-Bus interface
module-default-device-restore           Automatically restore the default sink and source
module-detect                           Detect available audio hardware and load matching drivers
module-device-manager                   Keep track of devices (and their descriptions) both past and present and prioritise by role
module-device-restore                   Automatically restore the volume/mute state of devices
module-echo-cancel                      Echo Cancellation
module-equalizer-sink                   General Purpose Equalizer
module-esound-sink                      ESOUND Sink
module-filter-apply                     Load filter sinks automatically when needed
module-filter-heuristics                Detect when various filters are desirable
module-http-protocol-tcp                HTTP (TCP sockets)
module-http-protocol-unix               HTTP (UNIX sockets)
module-intended-roles                   Automatically set device of streams based on intended roles of devices
module-ladspa-sink                      Virtual LADSPA sink
module-loopback                         Loopback from source to sink
module-match                            Playback stream expression matching module
module-mmkbd-evdev                      Multimedia keyboard support via Linux evdev
module-native-protocol-fd               Native protocol autospawn helper
module-native-protocol-tcp              Native protocol (TCP sockets)
module-native-protocol-unix             Native protocol (UNIX sockets)
module-null-sink                        Clocked NULL sink
module-null-source                      Clocked NULL source
module-oss                              OSS Sink/Source
module-pipe-sink                        UNIX pipe sink
module-pipe-source                      UNIX pipe source
module-position-event-sounds            Position event sounds between L and R depending on the position on screen of the widget triggering them.
module-remap-sink                       Virtual channel remapping sink
module-remap-source                     Virtual channel remapping source
module-rescue-streams                   When a sink/source is removed, try to move its streams to the default sink/source
module-role-cork                        Mute & cork streams with certain roles while others exist
module-role-ducking                     Apply a ducking effect based on streams roles
module-rtp-recv                         Receive data from a network via RTP/SAP/SDP
module-rtp-send                         Read data from source and send it to the network via RTP/SAP/SDP
module-rygel-media-server               UPnP MediaServer Plugin for Rygel
module-simple-protocol-tcp              Simple protocol (TCP sockets)
module-simple-protocol-unix             Simple protocol (UNIX sockets)
module-sine                             Sine wave generator
module-sine-source                      Sine wave generator source
module-stream-restore                   Automatically restore the volume/mute/device state of streams
module-suspend-on-idle                  When a sink/source is idle for too long, suspend it
module-switch-on-connect                When a sink/source is added, switch to it
module-switch-on-port-available         n/a
module-systemd-login                    Create a client for each login session of this user
module-tunnel-sink                      Tunnel module for sinks
module-tunnel-sink-new                  Create a network sink which connects via a stream to a remote PulseAudio server
module-tunnel-source                    Tunnel module for sources
module-tunnel-source-new                Create a network source which connects via a stream to a remote PulseAudio server
module-udev-detect                      Detect available audio hardware and load matching drivers
module-virtual-sink                     Virtual sink
module-virtual-source                   Virtual source
module-virtual-surround-sink            Virtual surround sink
module-volume-restore                   Compatibility module
module-x11-bell                         X11 bell interceptor
module-x11-cork-request                 Synthesize X11 media key events when cork/uncork is requested
module-x11-publish                      X11 credential publisher
module-x11-xsmp                         X11 session management
```

aplay -l:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
Failed to create secure directory (/run/user/1000/pulse): Permission denied
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

kern.log on restarting the MIDI communications program:

```
Aug 25 10:42:43 debianl016 pulseaudio[1584]: Failed to create secure directory (/run/user/1000/pulse): Permission denied
Aug 25 10:42:43 debianl016 pulseaudio[1584]: Failed to generate socket path.
Aug 25 10:42:43 debianl016 pulseaudio[1584]: Failed to load module "module-cli-protocol-unix" (argument: ""): initialization failed.
Aug 25 10:42:43 debianl016 pulseaudio[1584]: Failed to create secure directory (/run/user/1000/pulse): Permission denied
Aug 25 10:42:43 debianl016 pulseaudio[1584]: Failed to generate socket path.
Aug 25 10:42:43 debianl016 pulseaudio[1584]: Failed to load module "module-cli-protocol-unix" (argument: ""): initialization failed.
Aug 25 10:42:43 debianl016 pulseaudio[1584]: Failed to create secure directory (/run/user/1000/pulse): Permission denied
Aug 25 10:42:43 debianl016 pulseaudio[1584]: Failed to generate socket path.
Aug 25 10:42:43 debianl016 pulseaudio[1584]: Failed to load module "module-cli-protocol-unix" (argument: ""): initialization failed.
Aug 25 10:42:44 debianl016 pulseaudio[1584]: Failed to create secure directory (/run/user/1000/pulse): Permission denied
Aug 25 10:42:44 debianl016 pulseaudio[1584]: Failed to generate socket path.
Aug 25 10:42:44 debianl016 pulseaudio[1584]: Failed to load module "module-cli-protocol-unix" (argument: ""): initialization failed.
Aug 25 10:42:44 debianl016 pulseaudio[1584]: Failed to create secure directory (/run/user/1000/pulse): Permission denied
Aug 25 10:42:44 debianl016 pulseaudio[1584]: Failed to generate socket path.
Aug 25 10:42:44 debianl016 pulseaudio[1584]: Failed to load module "module-cli-protocol-unix" (argument: ""): initialization failed.
Aug 25 10:42:56 debianl016 pulseaudio[1584]: Failed to create secure directory (/run/user/1000/pulse): Permission denied
Aug 25 10:43:00 debianl016 pulseaudio[2110]: Stale PID file, overwriting.
Aug 25 10:43:00 debianl016 pulseaudio[2110]: Failed to find a working profile.
Aug 25 10:43:00 debianl016 pulseaudio[2110]: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="1" name="usb-CLASSIC_ORGAN_WORKS_CLASSIC_Lighted_Rockers_01-016_01-016-00-C01016" card_name="alsa_card.usb-CLASSIC_ORGAN_WORKS_CLASSIC_Lighted_Rockers_01-016_01-016-00-C01016" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
Aug 25 10:43:00 debianl016 pulseaudio[2110]: Unable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Aug 25 10:43:00 debianl016 pulseaudio[2110]: Unable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

CONCLUSION: I had to apt-get purge pulseaudio and remove pulse-related files in /usr/share/alsa in order for the MIDI program to work - it seems as if pulseaudio was interfering with the communication.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be "overwriting" the configuration that would normally be pulled from the system-wide `default.pa` file, with an blank one from the located `default.pa` file that belongs to your current user. This user-specific config file can be found in either `~/.pulse/default.pa` or `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` directory. If you can't find it, you can just run locate:

```bsh
sudo updatedb
locate default.pa
```

Unless you are already using user-specific pulse settings, you can test the solution by temporarily "hiding" the `~/.config/pulse/`(on some systems it may be `~/.pulse) directory with` mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/pulse.old` and restarting pulseaudio. This will automatically force pulseaudio to simply revert to using the default system-wide config file because it will be the only one found on the system.

Also if for some reason your system-wide `/etc/pulse/default.pa` file ever gets corrupted you can reinstall it with the following command:

```bsh
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confask" install --reinstall pulseaudio
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - I removed all /home/*/.config/pulse folders and did the hard reinstall. Now the errors are a bit more detailed and varied, as I have edited in the OP.

Comment: It looks like your `dbus`  is not initializing correctly . Could you try the following: 1. kill pulseaudio with `pulseaudio -k` , 2. execute `export $(dbus-launch)` and `xhost +` as user without sudo 3. Restart pulseaudio with `pulseaudio --start` as normal user. 4. Run these three commands and post their output above: `pulseaudio --dump-modules` , `pacmd --dump` and `aplay -l`

Comment: pulseaudio --start gives errors:
    `classic@debianl016:~$ pulseaudio --start
    E: [autospawn] core-util.c: Failed to create secure directory (/run/user/1000/pulse):    Permission denied

    W: [autospawn] lock-autospawn.c: Cannot access autospawn lock.
    E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to acquire autospawn lock`

Running chmod 0777 on the directory didn't help.

Comment: Updated main page with the other command results. pacmd could not run because pulseaudio wouldn't start

Comment: Solved the issue by uninstalling pulseaudio completely and removing some pulse files in /usre/share/alsa - seems like it was interfering with the MIDI program. See 'Conclusion". Thank you for your help